# Prevent client script being re-registered on back button or refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, post

I've got a GridView of results that gets populated based on a few input selections and a "Go" button.

After the grid is populated, there is a "Print" button.

This Print button stores the GridView data in a DataTable and stores it in the user Session.

It then registers an 'onload' javascript client script via to popup a new window with a print preview and options to print the page.

Problem is when I navigate away from the page and navigate back, and also when I refresh it, the print popup gets re-displayed, which I am guessing is because the `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` call get's re-registered somehow.

Is there a way I can explicitly clear the client script? I also don't know where in this lifecycle you would do the removal. Logically it could only be immediately after it being executed, because any other time, it might prevent it from ever running.

Here is my print button click code:

```
protected void btnPrintSummary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtPrint = ...
    Session["Print_DataTable"] = dtPrint;
    Session["Print_Sort"] = ViewState["Sort"];
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, Page.GetType(), "onload", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">OpenWindow('printpopup.aspx','print_patrol_summary',750,600,',scrollbars=yes');</script>", false);
}
```

Comment: do you have any `IsPostBack` checks ..? can you show the code for the `Page_Load` Event..

Comment: I could, it is quite long. Essentially it checks `if(!IsPostBack) ...load data for a default set of inputs and populate grid ...` It does not register any client scripts so I don't know if the code itself will help

Comment: well it would help in my opinion.. because you we would need to know what's being hit when the back button is pushed.. you could just set a bunch of breakpoints and see for yoursefl when stepping through the code to repeat the same thing.. have you tried that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `ClientScriptManager.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered` in the `page_load` to test if it's already been registered? In the case it has, just register it again with an empty script.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa5tktc9(v=vs.110).aspx) for more documentation.

Comment: How will this not clear out the script every time? It appears to me that the `onload` javascript function happen after `Page_Load`, so your solution would clear it out every time, even when I want it to run.